# Documentation for Rakuten Ichiba and Auctions API in English

Tags: api

I'm building and application that makes use of Rakuten Ichiba and Auctions API, but most of the documentation I have found until now is Japanese language (http://webservice.rakuten.co.jp).

Does anyone knows where to find English language information about Rakuten APIs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an English translation of Rakuten API documentation here:

http://rakuten-api-documentation.antoniotajuelo.com/

You can find comprehensive endpoint and parameter descriptions for all Rakuten services providing and API, information about how to generate an AppId, how to generate OAuth access tokens, sample requests and responses, and even a live API request testing tool.

Comment: is there any way to change the item's currency price via API? I only get JPY currency

Comment: Not at the moment.